# RewriteRule in .htaccess doesnt work

Tags: php, apache

I've never used something like "pretty urls" but i have to fix this and I just have no idea how.
So I have this function in php:

```
function niceUrl()
{
    // getting variable based on .htaccess
    $request = $_GET['tlederPageId'];
    var_dump($request);
    $vars = explode("/", $request);

    return $vars;
}
```

and this var_dump prints only NULL

and this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)(.*)/?$ index.php?tlederPageId=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

And I have no clue how should that work. I don't even know where to look for help. Could someone explain that to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesn't really help. Explain what URL you have, its conditions and what you'd like to point it to.

Comment: Am I wrong in asking that you just need this code explained?

Comment: At least explain "fix it" - that would enable us to help.

Comment: Oh wow, I just realized how misleading this title is, sorry. I just wanted an explanation. Those articles should be enough I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Alright lets break down the post you provided:
"pretty urls": usually defined as SEO friendly URLs, that describe two things

1, a particular category

2, a particular subject of that category

(Note) This doesn't mean that your subject has to have a category

using example one from above a pretty URL could contain something like:
    http://www.animals.com/dogs/

using example two from from above a pretty URL could contain something like:
    http://www.animals.com/dogs/bulldogs/

using the 'notes' from above: having a relative domain name doesn't necessarily have to have a category in order to have a subject; something like:
    http://www.bulldogs.com/american-bulldogs/

concerning your ".htaccess" this line seems strange to me:

```
RewriteRule (.*)(.*)/?$ index.php?tlederPageId=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

as having `(.*)(.*)` would be the same as saying [ANYTHING + ANYTHING = ANYTHING]
although your .htaccess would forward any request to a file in your root directory called index.php with a $_GET variable of tlederPageId as well as any additional query string that were passed.

It would then be your job to ensure that the URL being passed to would, first through apache then through php would validate.

For instance: If you caught "tlederPageId" and did some pre-processing, through PHP, with the variables and determined that the URL was not valid (ex: http://www.bulldogs.com/boxers/), it is your responsibility to throw a 404, where as if someone passed a valid URL you would accept the URL as 200 OK. These need to be set in the php headers.

Comment: To be honest this is my friends site and he just asked me to fix this for him.
I'm not sure if I understood what you meant, but this page is in a folder "page.com/test/page" and there is a link to : 1/2012/test. So it gives me page.com/test/page/1/2012/test and using this function
niceUrl() I always get null.